# Bug counting characters after edit?

Tags: bug

I've done an edit in my answer, and it showed *7 characters added in body*, but I've not added nothing.. =X

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing two things here:

1. You just missed the 5-minute grace period window by about 10 seconds, suggesting you probably opened the edit window *before* the grace period ended.
2. The edit reason is exactly the same as the previous edit reason.

When you open the edit screen on a post and you're *still within the grace period*, it also loads the previous edit reason you had into the box so you can modify it with any additional changes you make to the post. If the grace period does expire while you're still editing, it will use that same edit reason for the new edit that gets created.

The edit reason only gets automatically filled with those blurbs when you submit a new edit with an *empty edit reason*. Since you had filled something in - or still had the "added 7 characters in body" from the previous edit - it used that text and didn't automatically insert anything into that edit reason.